# Validating a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, validation

I have a parent form with one DataGridView and a button. When the button is clicked, it opens a child window and when closed, goes back to the parent form. I want to validate the value being inputted in a cell of the DAtaGridView. I'm using CellValidated event and showing a message box whenever it inputs an invalid value. However, when I click on the button to open the child window and close it back, the DataGridView becomes just a white box with a diagonal cross, and a NullReferenceException shows.

Does anyone know what causes this issue? If not, what's the best way to validate a value of the cell and which event to put it in?

Answer (score 0):

Just setup Visual Studio as described in this article: [How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx). This way, you will be able to catch this exception in the debugger, and see where its roots are.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever validating a cell in a `DataGridView`, you should use the [CellValidating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx).

You can get the data using the [DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs.aspx) and set the `Cancel` property to `True` if it is invalid data. This is gonna prevent the `CellValidated event` from being raised and should give the focus back to the given cell.

If this doesn't help, can you provide some code and show us where the exception occured?